# Bluetooth Low Energy used in Contact Tracing Applications (Mobile Devices)

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

I am researching on Bluetooth Low Energy used in contact tracing applications on mobile devices. I am attempting to do a replay and relay attack to prove that the protocols put in place are not strong enough. Since contact tracing devices act as centrals and peripherals to communicate with each other and exchange information such as the user's ID, I used GAttacker to man-in-the-middle and extract the GATT services and characteristics to obtain these information and succeeded in obtaining the user's ID amongst other information.

I attempted to launch a relay attack from Laptop A at location A with a mobile device A active to Laptop B at location B with another mobile device B. The distance between the two locations is around 15m with walls in between. Laptop B at location B will spoof the identity of mobile device A with the extracted advertisement and services files. I succeeded in initializing the connection from Laptop B to Laptop A and back to Device A and Laptop B began advertising as mobile device A.

In theory, mobile device B is supposed to discover this advertisement and connect to Laptop B to retrieve the GATT services which includes mobile device A's user ID and other information. Mobile device B should then return its own userID back to Laptop B before closing the connection.

However, there was no connections made to Laptop B from mobile device B. Oddly enough, after analyzing the contact tracing application database of mobile device B, it did in fact recorded down mobile device A's userID which could only mean mobile device B did connect to Laptop B and read the GATT services and characteristics. Furthermore, the timestamp of the recording matches the time when I launched the attack.

I have several questions pertaining to this:

1. Why did GAttacker on Laptop B not show that mobile device B connect?
2. If mobile device B did not connect to Gattacker on Laptop B, how did it read and record the userID of mobile device A at location A? BLE devices can only read characteristics of GATT services upon successful connection between 2 devices.

Comment: Bluetooth Low Energy allows for information to be shared without a connection. Advertisements support custom data. Do you have a way to look at the actual advertisements you send/receive?

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan Yes, after reading up more, I realized information can be captured of the advertisement packet itself. This is probably what happened as I found out that the contact tracing application has 2 protocols to retrieve data, one that requires a connection and one that does not.

However, I am unsure why the other protocol that requires a connection does not work. In theory, mobile device B should connect to Laptop B and via GATT to request to read the specified service and specified characteristics uuid.

Comment: My knowledge of the contact tracing API is pretty limited, but my understanding was that the apps advertise a UUID that changes every few minutes. The UUIDs are saved on both sides and if you mark a Covid test as positive in your app the uuids of the last days are uploaded which triggers the warning in the apps that collected your UUID through an advertisement. This document by Google and Apple describes the procedure as well: https://covid19-static.cdn-apple.com/applications/covid19/current/static/contact-tracing/pdf/ExposureNotification-BluetoothSpecificationv1.2.pdf